# No grub display after installing aside Windows 7

Tags: 11.04, installation, windows-7, grub2

I had a win 7 (32 bit) on dell vostro 1500(T9300cpu). Now I installed natty and restart but no grub were displayed.

I give 8Gb to root and 2Gb to swap and about 8.5Gb to home section. Root and home are ext4 partition format.

What's the problem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you remember where you installed GRUB? Was it to the MBR?

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the main GRUB configuration file (`/etc/default/grub`) and changing `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to a different value.

One way to edit the file is to run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You can also try tapping or holding up/down keys right before Ubuntu starts up.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Natty onto a separate drive than Windows 7 (a USB hard-drive that I had been using for backup), and when I reboot there is no GRUB.  But when I choose boot options (on my Dell I press F12 during boot), then I can choose either my internal hard-drive or my USB hard-drive (amongst other options, of course); when I choose to boot to my USB hard-drive, I get GRUB!

Perhaps if you installed Natty onto a different drive that Windows, you might need to choose that drive and THEN Natty, just as I do.

Answer (score 0):

After ObsessiveFOSS advice:

From [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1035999) link...

#### Step 1: Boot from the ubuntu live cd and go to terminal

Type in terminal:

```
sudo grub
grub> find /boot/grub/stage1
```

That should return your Ubuntu partition in the form of **(hdX,Y)**, use that:

```
grub> root (hdX,Y)
grub> setup (hd0)
grub> quit
```

(You don’t need to type the `grub>`  part.)

That has re-installed grub but you can no longer see Windows 7.

#### Step 2. Edit the main GRUB configuration file.

Boot into Ubuntu, open a Terminal, and type:

```
gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

A large text file will open and at the bottom leave a line and add this:

```
title    windows 7 beta (Loader)
root     (hd0,1)
savedefault
makeactive
chainloader +1
```

(Do not type this line but if that does not work on re-boot try “hdo,0 or hd0,2” and so on until it works.)

Now that is done you can re-boot into Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: I edited my answer as you adviced... thanks for this comment :)